# Ignore unpickleable objects when pickling

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization

I have a rather unique case where my Python program generates a large amount of dynamic code (such as dynamically generated classes and lambdas), and it needs to save its state with Pickle. I'd like to preserve *as much as possible*, but it's acceptable to simply fail to preserve objects that are unpickleable.

In other words, I'd like to be able to pickle the dict `mydict`, which contains some unpickleable objects, by simply executing `del mydict[unpickleablekey]` for every unpickleable object.

What's the simplest and most Pythonic way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue when trying to serialize JSON with instances that could not be pickled.  I wrote a custom JSON encoder which may help in your case.

```
from json import JSONEncoder
class JsonEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        return repr(obj)
```

Then you would use it like so:

```
encoded_dict = JsonEncoder().encode(mydict)
with open('dump.pkl', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(encoded_dict, f)
```

To read it back:

```
import json
with open('dump.pkl', 'r') as f:
    decoded_dict = json.loads(pickle.load(f))
```

One thing to note is that by using the repr to encode values will cause things like integer or float values will be converted to a string representation and not the true type.  The default encoder can be enhanced to only return the repr if the type is not int, float, etc...